# Speed up a view only stored procedure return

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using EF in a context but a query to a  view is rather slow I was wanting to use `.AsNoTracking` to see if it speeds it up as it is only a view of data no changes being made.

```
public static List<VitaminMovementView> FetchAll(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    var storeVitamins = new List<VitaminMovementView>();

    using (var cxt = new xxxEntities())
    {
        storeVitamins.AddRange(cxt.VitaminMovementViews.Where(x => x.Date >= fromDate && x.Date <= toDate).OrderByDescending(sm => sm.VitaminMovementID));
    }

    return storeVitamins;
}
```

I was trying to follow the article here. I am using database first in an old application so not to sure if it is avail to  me here.

http://www.krisvandermast.com/post/2018/02/03/Use-AsNoTracking-to-speed-up-Entity-Framework-performance.html

Was wondering if any one had an idea how to do that but I am not to sure of how to achieve that.

Comment: Yes include AsNoTracking() plus how many records you are fetching ?

Comment: I believe you would just add `AsNoTracking` before the `Where`.

Comment: @NetMage Yes but I am using 4.0 cant upgrade as its a stable project i am afraid

Comment: v4.0 of what? Perhaps you should mention those details in your question?